# "MySQL Server has gone away" on simple select

Tags: mysql, connection

I get a MySQL server has gone away error on a simple query.

```
mysql> select version();
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1
```

A query such as select id from users limit 1; can also result in this error. Most search results are about inserts or imports so I'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? may you can find something useful on data directory\machinename.log or error.log.

Comment: +--------------+
    | version()    |
    +--------------+
    | 5.1.49-1-log |
    +--------------+
    1 row in set (40.16 sec)

Comment: What do your logs say?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the select, it very likely your interactive timeout setting. MySQL will shutdown idle connections after a period of time. So if you don't type anything for a while, MySQL will drop the connection. What you are seeing is an auto reconnect.

You can change your wait_timeout and interactive_timeout settings if you like. This is unlikely a problem in your code since it is never idle long enough for the connection to drop. Unless you have some long running code.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Well actually, I just opened mysql and that was my first query that I posted here. I'm using SSH and doing this with root access on both the server and mysql.